# android audio visualization

Tags: android

I am trying to develop app which will have visualizer for audio input.

I am using `android.media.audiofx.Visualizer` class for this.

But not able to initialize Visualizer object.

Reference :  https://github.com/felixpalmer/android-visualizer/blob/master/src/com/pheelicks/visualizer/VisualizerView.java

Here is my code :

```
private MediaPlayer mPlayer;
private byte[] mBytes;
private byte[] mFFTBytes;
private Visualizer mVisualizer;

mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.test);
        mPlayer.setLooping(false);
        mPlayer.start();

mVisualizer = new Visualizer(mPlayer.getAudioSessionId());
        mVisualizer.setCaptureSize(Visualizer.getCaptureSizeRange()[1]);

    Visualizer.OnDataCaptureListener captureListener = new Visualizer.OnDataCaptureListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onWaveFormDataCapture(Visualizer visualizer, byte[] bytes,
                int samplingRate)
        {
            System.out.println("onWaveFormDataCapture");
        }

        @Override
        public void onFftDataCapture(Visualizer visualizer, byte[] bytes,
                int samplingRate)
        {
            System.out.println("onFftDataCapture");
        }
    };

    mVisualizer.setDataCaptureListener(captureListener,
            Visualizer.getMaxCaptureRate() / 2, true, false);

    mVisualizer.setEnabled(true);
    mPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer)
        {
            mVisualizer.setEnabled(false);
        }
    });
```

Please help me with this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What error are you getting when you run your code?

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.android.trial.sounddataextraction/com.android.trial.sounddataextraction.SoundDataExtractionActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot initialize Visualizer engine, error: -4

Comment: Which line in your code does it get to? There's a couple of possibilities, and knowing which line in the source is the problem will help narrow things down.

Comment: mVisualizer = new Visualizer(mPlayer.getAudioSessionId());

Comment: Got it what I was doing wrong. I was testing my app on emulator. Instead of that I should have tested it on device. It works fine on device. Thanks for replying.

Answer (score 0):

Error -4 means you've passed a bad value as a parameter (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/audiofx/Visualizer.html#ERROR_BAD_VALUE)

1. Can you check whether `Visualizer.getCaptureSizeRange()[1]` is actually a power of 2? It ought to be, but if it isn't, you'll be setting the capture size range to a number that isn't a power of 2, which causes this error.
2. Can you check what `mPlayer.getAudioSessionId()` is returning? If it's a bad value, e.g. if initialization of `mPlayer` hasn't completely finished, that could be causing the error.

Comment: Already checked for that. 1) Visualizer.getCaptureSizeRange()[1] returns 1024       2) mPlayer.getAudioSessionId() returning integer so I think its initialized.

Comment: But what integer? From what you've said it seems likely that it's returning an integer that doesn't correspond to a valid session. For example, if it's 0, that means there was an error in constructing the !MediaPlayer. This could happen if you've forgotten to add the `RECORD_AUDIO` permission.

Comment: Already added RECORD_AUDIO permission. And I am getting non zero integer. Tried to print value for audio session id. Shows non zero integer.

Comment: Got it what I was doing wrong. I was testing my app on emulator. Instead of that I should have tested it on device. It works fine on device. Thanks for replying.